# Typescript cannot find interface from a different directory

Tags: typescript

I do have 2 main folders in my project:

- `src/*.ts`
- `test/*.test.ts`

In the src folder there is a interface named `IImportRow.ts`

```
interface IImportRow {
    transactionId?: string;
    transactionApiId?: string;
    ...
}
```

this interface can be found for every other ts file in the `src` folder.

However in the `test` folder the TS cannot find the interface

```
var row: IImportRow = {
    transactionId: '10',
    ...
};
```

> [ts] Cannot find name 'IImportRow'.

Is this an expected behaviour? What should I do in order to fix it?

here are my `tsconfig.json` configuration

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an additional portion of the TsConfig file which lets you specifies which directories should be included/excluded for inspection by the TS compiler. You just need to add your tests folder to the `include` array. Here's an example from one of my projects that you can tweak as needed.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: you men to add the "src" folder instead of "test" right?

Comment: I believe you would need to add both in your situation